# Behavour of Jacobi Theta Functions in the limit of degenerate lattice

Tags: complex-analysis

I don't understand how the Jacobi Theta functions behave as the lattice parameter $\tau$ tends to a rational number:

$\Theta(z;q) \rightarrow ?$

for $\vert q\vert \rightarrow 1$, where $q=e^{\pi i \tau}$.

Is there a way to study this limit?
Thank you.

Comment: What is the Fourier series of the smooth periodic function $f(t) = \sum_n e^{-\pi (t-n)^2 s}, \Re(s) > 0$ ?